# Chromatic Polynomials from a graph

Tags: java, recursion, graph, polynomial-math

I have an assignment where I have to compute the Chromatic Polynomials of a graph. According to the “Fundamental Reduction Theorem”:

A recursive way of computing the chromatic polynomial is based on edge contraction: for a pair of adjacent vertices u and v the graph Guv is obtained by merging the two vertices and removing the edge between them. Then the chromatic polynomial satisfies the recurrence relation:

P(G, x) = P(G − uv, x) − P(Guv, x)

where u and v are adjacent vertices and G − uv is the graph with the edge uv removed.
Likewise, Chromatic Polynomials can be found when by: 
A recursive way of computing the chromatic polynomial is based on edge contraction: for a pair of non-adjacent vertices u and v the graph Guv is obtained by merging the two vertices and adding the edge between them. Then the chromatic polynomial satisfies the recurrence relation

P(G, x) = P(G + uv, x) + P(Guv, x)

where u and v are adjacent vertices and G + uv is the graph with the edge uv added.

It was determined for this assignment that when we want to make null graphs based on the previous formula was when the edges of the graph is <= (the number of vertices) * ((number of vertices-1)/4). This is the “break point” for determining if it is more efficient to go toward null graphs or complete graphs.

Additionally, I have a class for creating Polynomials. So I don’t have to post two classes I’ll the Polynomial class here summarize here:

Constructors:
Polynomial() – creates a constant polynomial P(x) = 1.

Polynomial(int a)- creates a linear polynomial of the form P(x) = x + a.

Polynomial(int a, int b) – creates a polynomial of the form a * x^b.

int degree() – returns the degree of the polynomial.

Polynomial plus(Polynomial b) – returns the sum of this polynomial and b, i.e, c = this + b

Polynomial minus(Polynomial b) – returns the difference of this polynomial and , i.e, c = this–b

Polynomial times(Polynomial b) – returns the product of this polynomial and b, return (this*b)

Polynomial compose(Polynomial b)- returns the composite of this polynomial and b. return this(b(x)) – compute using Horner’s method.

boolean equals(Polynomial b)- returns true whenever this polynomial and b are identical.

int evaluate(int x)- evaluate this polynomial at x. return this(x).

Polynomial differentiate()- return the derivative of the polynomial.

String toString()- return the textual representation of this polynomial.

The following is the Graph class. It uses a Bag data structure array that is implemented using a linked list. So for example, all vertices that are adjacent to vertex 0 will be in the Bag located at Bag[0]. I need help doing the recursive part where it computes a Chromatic Polynomial. I have some comments of questions I have in the chromaticPolynomial method as well as mergeVertices method. I am not sure if what I am thinking in these two methods is correct and would appreciate anyone’s help on it. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Graph {
private final int V;
private int E;
private Bag<Integer>[] adj;

  /**
  * Create an empty graph with V vertices.
  */
   public Graph(int V) {
     if (V < 0) throw new RuntimeException("Number of vertices must be nonnegative");
    this.V = V;
    this.E = 0;
    adj = (Bag<Integer>[]) new Bag[V];
    for (int v = 0; v < V; v++) {
        adj[v] = new Bag<Integer>();
    }
}

 /**
 * Create a random graph with V vertices and E edges.
 * Expected running time is proportional to V + E.
 */
public Graph(int V, int E) {
    this(V);
    if (E < 0) throw new RuntimeException("Number of edges must be nonnegative");
    for (int i = 0; i < E; i++) {
        int v = (int) (Math.random() * V);
        int w = (int) (Math.random() * V);
        addEdge(v, w);
    }
}

   /**  
   * Create a digraph from input stream.
   */
   public Graph(In in) {
    this(in.readInt());
    int E = in.readInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < E; i++) {
        int v = in.readInt();
        int w = in.readInt();
        addEdge(v, w);
    }
}

    /**
   * Copy constructor.
   */
   public Graph(Graph G) {
    this(G.V());
    this.E = G.E();
    for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++) {
        // reverse so that adjacency list is in same order as original
        Stack<Integer> reverse = new Stack<Integer>();

        for (int w : G.adj[v]) {
            reverse.push(w);
        }


        for (int w : reverse) {
            adj[v].add(w);
        }        
    }
}

  /**
 * Return the number of vertices in the graph.
 */
public int V() { return V; }

 /**
 * Return the number of edges in the graph.
 */
  public int E() { return E; }


 /**
 * Add the edge v-w to graph.
 */
public void addEdge(int v, int w) {
    E++;
    adj[v].add(w);
    adj[w].add(v);
}

/**
* Remove edge from v-w to graph.
*/
public void removeEdge(int v, int w){
    E--;
    adj[v].remove(w);
    adj[w].remove(v); 
}

public Polynomial chromaticPolynomial(Graph G){
    // null graph is reached, return a polynomial that is G1.minus(G2)
    if(G.V() == 0) return new Polynomial(); // how do I create a Chromatic Polynomial when this condition is reached?

    // complete graph is reached, return a polynomial that is G1.plus(G2). If the number of vertices in a complete graph is n, then the number of edges is equal to n(n-1)/2.
    if(G.E() == ((G.V() - (G.V() - 1))/2)) return new Polynomial(); // how do I create a Chromatic Polynomial when this condtion is reached?

    // head toward a null graph.
    if(G.E() <= G.V()*(G.V()-1/4)){
        /**
            for every vertex (u) and every edge (v) from that vertex, create a graph that has an edge removed (G1)
            and a graph with merged vertices (G2), then recurse until a null graph is reached.
        */
        for(int u = 0; u < G.V(); u++){
            for(int v : adj[u]){
                Graph G1 = new Graph(G);
                Graph G2 = new Graph(G);
                G1.removeEdge(u,v);
                G2.mergeVertices(u,v);
                chromaticPolynomial(G1);
                chromaticPolynomial(G2);
                // reutrn a polynomial here?
            }
        }           
    }
    // head towards a complete graph.
    else{
        /**
            for every vertex (u) and every edge (v) from that vertex, create a graph that has an edge added (G1) and
            a graph with merged verticies (G2), then recures unitl all these graphs are a complete graph.
        */
        for(int u = 0; u < G.V(); u++){
            for(int v : adj[u]){
                Graph G1 = new Graph(G);
                Graph G2 = new Graph(G);
                G1.addEdge(u,v);
                G2.mergeVertices(u,v);
                chromaticPolynomial(G1);
                chromaticPolynomial(G2);
                // return a polynomial here?
            }
        }
    }
    // return nothing. It didn't work. 
    return null; 
}

public void mergeVertices(int vert1, int vert2){
        // edge has already been removed between these two.
        // just have to renumber the vertices so one is "removed"
        /**
            does this look correct?
        */
        for(int u = 0; u < this.V(); u++){
            for(int w: adj[u]){
                if(w > vert1 || w > vert2) w--;
                if(u > vert1 || u > vert2) u--;
            }
        }

}

 /**
 * Return the list of neighbors of vertex v as in Iterable.
 */
public Iterable<Integer> adj(int v) {
    return adj[v];
}


 /**
 * Return a string representation of the graph.
 */
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    s.append(V + " vertices, " + E + " edges " + NEWLINE);
    for (int v = 0; v < V; v++) {
        s.append(v + ": ");
        for (int w : adj[v]) {
            s.append(w + " ");
        }
        s.append(NEWLINE);
    }


    return s.toString();
}
```